# what is this bone for?

Tags: rigging, bones

Some pre-made rigs (in this case from make human) split tibia (main bone in lower-leg) into two. Beyond animating a fracture (which doesn't seem like a very common use-case) I struggle to find uses for this bone. I'm new to rigging, so I guess I'm missing something.

Is there a reasons to split lower part of the leg into two?

[image: this bone]

Comment: It's a twist bone.  It is intended to be rotated only in its Y axis, to distribute any axial rotation from the knee to the foot, because those kinds of rotations don't look good when applied at either the knee or the foot.

Comment: This is a great anwer @nathan. If you copy & paste it as an actual answer, I'll happily accept it.